# How to create a box inside a grid that contains an image and labels

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

How can I create a grid in which i can put a box like structure that contains an image and a label using xamarin.forms.

I am posting the image which shows what I need

"I" refers to the Image
"N" refers to the number 
"W" refers to the text

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are two separate components here.

First is the creation of a custom layout you need for the image, number and text.

The second is how you then display that custom layout inside your page.

The Grid is certainly a possibility for the second component, but you really don't need it for the first one. Especially because nesting grids inside Xamarin.Forms thrashes layout performance.

So use either two stack layouts or a relative layout.

For the former

```
StackLayout box = new StackLayout {
Orientation = Vertical
};

StackLayout firstRow = new StackLayout {
Orientation = Horizontal
};
firstRow.Children.Add(new Image {Source="FileName.png"});
firstRow.Children.Add(new Label {Text="1", HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End});
box.Children.Add(firstRow);
box.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "This is the text" });
```

Or for the latter, something like

```
RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout();
var image = new Image {Source="FileName.png"};
var numberLabel = new Label {Text="1"};
var textLabel = new Label{Text="This is the text"};

rl.Children.Add(image,Constraint.Constant(0),Constraint.Constant(0)); //Add image at 0,0 = top left
rl.Children.Add(numberLabel,Constraint.RelativeToParrent(parent=>parent.Width - numberLabel.Width),Constraint.Constant(0)); // add numberLabel at the top right corner of the relative layout
rl.Children.Add(textLabel,Constraint.RelativeToView(image,(sibling,parent) => sibling.Y + sibling.Height + 20),Constraint.Constant(0)); // Add text label below the image, on the left side of the relative layout
```

Comment: You can experiment further with these options to get the full desired effect. If you have a more specific question or get stuck, post a question or update this one and I'll try and help.

Comment: The name 'Vertical' does not exist in the current context error is coming

Comment: if i have to give the border to that box

Comment: and if i have to create nested in every row 2 box

Comment: if i will use frame for box like struture then inside that i need all these thing